# How to center a large symbol on the origin in KiCad

Tags: kicad

In Symbol Editor I drew a quite large symbol for an MCU.
I want to center it (I mean the rectangle that define its symbol) on the origin point.

I cannot find a way to do this precisely.
I'm using KiCad 5.1.6.

Comment: Are you talking about centring the parts of the footprint in the footprint editor, or centring the compete footprint on the board in the PCB editor?

Comment: He's talking about the symbol, not the footprint.

Comment: Can't you always edit the coordinates numerically?  A pocket calculator has often seemed like a necessary accessory though I discovered yesterday while abusing it to design a sailboat compass size adapter that "[number]/2" is accepted in some fields!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do what you want with the current feature set. (I am not even aware that something like this is currently planned for a future release but i might have missed something. Head over to gitlab and check if it is at least requested)

---

You might even consider changing strategy to be honest. If the symbol is so large that it gets hard to see if it is centered then i guess it might benefit from being split into multiple smaller units. A typical split is to separate per GPIO section and separate units for power supply, crystal connections, programming interface, ....

That will allow your schematic to be made easier to read.

Comment: Got it. Anyway, the problem is not how large is the symbol (not so much, by the way) but the fact a CAD asks to use my eyes to do things...